# ¿Por qué en este algoritmo funcionan todas las opciones pero al introducir el número 4 como última opción el resultado es undefined?

Tags: javascript, array, bucles, while

En este caso el usuario tiene varias opciones para escoger productos. Todo funciona bien desde la opción 1 hasta la 3 pero al introducir la número 4, que sería la última opción, e intentar mostrar el contenido del producto, arroja undefined (última línea del código, para mostrar "content" por consola). ¿Por qué con las demás opciones si funciona? No entiendo el por qué. ¿El problema estará en el while? ¿Algún otro lado?

```
const cantidadFlores = []
cantidadFlores.push(new Contenido(6, 0, 2, 1))
cantidadFlores.push(new Contenido(12, 3, 4, 2))
cantidadFlores.push(new Contenido(0, 6, 3, 2))
cantidadFlores.push(new Contenido(3, 3, 2, 1))
console.log(cantidadFlores)

const tiposRamos = []
tiposRamos.push(new Ramos(1, 'Simple', 500, cantidadFlores[0]))
tiposRamos.push(new Ramos(2, 'Extra', 1000, cantidadFlores[1]))
tiposRamos.push(new Ramos(3, 'Elegante', 1300, cantidadFlores[2]))
tiposRamos.push(new Ramos(4, 'Fresco', 800, cantidadFlores[3]))
console.log(tiposRamos)

let ramoElegido = 0
function ingreseRamo() {
  ramoElegido = Number(
    prompt(
      'Ingrese el ramo que desea comprar:' +
        '\n' +
        '1)Simple \n2)Extra \n3)Elegante \n4)Fresco',
    ),
  )
  while (ramoElegido < 1 || ramoElegido >4) {
    ramoElegido = Number(
      prompt(
        'Ingrese el nombre de un ramo válido:' +
          '\n' +
          '1)Simple \n2)Extra \n3)Elegante \n4)Fresco',
      ),
    )
  }
  return ramoElegido
}

ingreseRamo()
console.log(ramoElegido)
let content = cantidadFlores[ramoElegido]

console.log(content)
```

Comment: ¿Será porque los arreglos están indexados a partir del 0? Tu arreglo tiene 4 elementos, por lo tanto sus índices válidos van del 0 al 3. Cuando introduces el número 4, el índice 4 está fuera de los índices del arreglo, por lo tanto es undefined. Tu while no tiene sentido. Deberías restar a tu opción  -1 y posteriormente validar `while(ramo >= 0 && ramo < tipoRamos.length)`

Comment: Tu while está bien, solo debes restar -1 a la opción seleccionada para ajustar tu valor a los índices del arreglo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He resuelto el caso debido a los comentarios de @jacobo y entendí que cuando escoges la opción número 4 (las otras 3 funcionan perfectamente), si chequeaba por la consola al escoger dicha opción arrojaba "undefined" en la línea 40, y este "undefined" era solo la consecuencia pues allí solo mostraba un resultado. La verdadera causa está en la línea 38 donde está almacenada la variable "content", pues es cierto que los arrays están indexados a partir del 0 (cero). El arreglo tiene 4 elementos, por lo tanto sus índices válidos van del 0 al 3. Cuando el usuario introduce el número 4 como opción pero no se ajusta su valor al índice del array, dicho valor representaría la posición 5 en el array y este estaría fuera del índice del mismo, por lo tanto es "undefined". Para solucionar esto se debe de restar 1 a la que será la opción elegida por el usuario, en este caso, ramoElegido, en la línea 38 [ramoElegido-1] perteneciente a la variable "content" y de esta manera se habrá ajustado este valor (opción del usuario) a los índices del array.

```
const cantidadFlores = []
cantidadFlores.push(new Contenido(6, 0, 2, 1))
cantidadFlores.push(new Contenido(12, 3, 4, 2))
cantidadFlores.push(new Contenido(0, 6, 3, 2))
cantidadFlores.push(new Contenido(3, 3, 2, 1))
console.log(cantidadFlores)

const tiposRamos = []
tiposRamos.push(new Ramos(1, 'Simple', 500, cantidadFlores[0]))
tiposRamos.push(new Ramos(2, 'Extra', 1000, cantidadFlores[1]))
tiposRamos.push(new Ramos(3, 'Elegante', 1300, cantidadFlores[2]))
tiposRamos.push(new Ramos(4, 'Fresco', 800, cantidadFlores[3]))
console.log(tiposRamos)

let ramoElegido = 0
function ingreseRamo() {
  ramoElegido = Number(
    prompt(
      'Ingrese el ramo que desea comprar:' +
        '\n' +
        '1)Simple \n2)Extra \n3)Elegante \n4)Fresco',
    ),
  )
  while (ramoElegido < 1 || ramoElegido > 4) {
    ramoElegido = Number(
      prompt(
        'Ingrese el nombre de un ramo válido:' +
          '\n' +
          '1)Simple \n2)Extra \n3)Elegante \n4)Fresco',
      ),
    )
  }
  return ramoElegido
}

ingreseRamo()
console.log(ramoElegido)
let content = cantidadFlores[ramoElegido-1]

console.log(content)
```

Comment: Y esto es...????

Comment: La respuesta a mi pregunta. No sé si está realizada de manera correcta o si yo mismo me respondo, ¿debo de realizarlo de otro modo?

Comment: Esta perfecto que te respondas, pero agrega una explicación del código describiendo que es lo que hace, cual era el error y como solucionas el error, lee [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: OK, muy bien, entendido...